# Recursive List containing Lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, recursion

```
from random import choice

def Number_recursive(N):
    if N < 0:
        raise ValueError('N must be positive')
    if N == 0:
        return []
    return [choice((0, 1))] + Number_recursive(N-1)
```

How would I put another list in this list.
Currently it outputs let's put N equal to 4 `[1,0,0,1]` randomly of course.

But I'd like to get it to read out a list containing `N` number of lists. The goal:

```
[ [0,1,1,0],[1,0,0,1],[1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1] ]
```

Comment: You want a list of size `N x N` ?

Comment: @ Anand S Kumar Correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do this would be to use list comprehension to create the sub-list instead of `[choice((0, 1))]` . Example -

```
from random import choice

def Number_recursive(N,initialN=None):
    initialN = initialN or N
    if N < 0:
        raise ValueError('N must be positive')
    if N == 0:
        return []
    return [[choice((0, 1)) for _ in range(initialN)]] + Number_recursive(N-1,initialN)
```

Demo -

```
>>> from random import choice
>>>
>>> def Number_recursive(N,M=None):
...     M = M or N
...     if N < 0:
...         raise ValueError('N must be positive')
...     if N == 0:
...         return []
...     return [[choice((0, 1)) for _ in range(M)]] + Number_recursive(N-1,M)
...
>>> Number_recursive(4)
[[0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks it works! .... Just because I love headaches, say I wanted to replace the for _ in and wanted to do that recursively. Any ideas?

Comment: You can create a new recursive function pass it `M` and have it create list that you are going to put inside Like `return [newRecursiveFunc(initialN)] + Number_recursive(N-1,initialN)` . And this new recursive function would be exactly same as your original function.

Comment: I don't think I quiet follow... This is what I have so far    `[[choice((0, 1))] + Number_recursive(N-1)] + Number_recursive(N-1,N)`

Comment: No, I mean use the function I gave above, just replace the return line with - `return [newRecursiveFunc(initialN)] + Number_recursive(N-1,initialN)` . And then define a function called `newRecursiveFunc` which has the same code as your original `Number_recursive()` .

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this, Hope this helps.

```
from random import choice
N = 4
def Number_recursive(N):
    if N < 0:
        raise ValueError('N must be positive')
    if N == 0:
        return []
    return [choice((0, 1))] + Number_recursive(N-1)

result = []
for i in range(0, N):
    result.append(Number_recursive(N))

print result
```